# ENS - Signature Verification

Tags: marketing-cloud, crypto, transactional-messaging-api

I followed the Transactional API Notification Signing steps as mentioned in the document [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-get-started.htm).

And I get following signature key as a response on calling the endpoint `/platform/v1/ens-callbacks`

```
//Request
Host: https://domain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /platform/v1/ens-subscriptions
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Body:
[{
    "callbackId": "65b885ab-c2b4-46fe-85d0-d6cb8be8057d",
    "subscriptionName": "testsub",
    "eventCategoryTypes": ["TransactionalSendEvents.EmailNotSent",
    "TransactionalSendEvents.EmailSent"],
    "filters": ["definitionKey=test"]
}]

Response
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
[{
    "callbackName": "test",
    "callbackId": "65b885ab-c2b2-46fe-85d0-d6cb8be8057d",
    "url": "https://example.com/",
    "signatureKey":"C27FXfqI3DnifQW1bhFDeJixpt8eDAY5R24UJI3cK7N=",
    "maxBatchSize": 1000
}]
```

The signature key is definitely not PKCS8 format.

As per the document [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/ens-notification-signing.htm), I wrote following code in Apex to check the signature

```
String algorithmName = 'RSA-SHA256';
String privatKey = 'C27FXfqI3DnifQW1bhFDeJixpt8eDAY5R24UJI3cK7N='; // signature I received above
String publiKey = 'AKEher92u3TbgxoZNe9hBMLNrj0WyH+uX1TiNxUdGfU=';  // public key in Header of request
Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(privatKey);
Blob publicKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(publiKey);
Blob input = req.requestBody;
Blob signature = Crypto.sign(algorithmName, input, privateKey);
Boolean verified = Crypto.verify(algorithmName, input, signature, publicKey);
System.debug(verified);
```

This results in error

> System.SecurityException: Invalid Crypto Key

I am not sure how to validate the signature using Apex.

Comment: You want `Crypto.verifyHmac('hmacSHA256',...)`

Comment: i am getting error at line `Blob signature = Crypto.sign(algorithmName, input, privateKey);`

Comment: ....because you are supposed to be using `Crypto.verifyHmac('hmacSHA256',...)`

Comment: perfect! that solved the problem :) you are awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

credits: [@identigral](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4142/identigral)

Following solved the issue

> Replaced `verify` with `verifyHmac`

Resulting code:

```
String algorithmName = 'hmacSHA256';
String privatKey = 'C27FXfqI3DnifQW1bhFDeJixpt8eDAY5R24UJI3cK7N='; // signature I received above
String publiKey = 'AKEher92u3TbgxoZNe9hBMLNrj0WyH+uX1TiNxUdGfU=';  // public key in Header of request
Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(privatKey);
Blob publicKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(publiKey);
Blob input = req.requestBody;
Boolean verified = Crypto.verifyHmac(algorithmName, input, privateKey, publicKey);
System.debug(verified);
```